# Laravel remove index element from get collection

Tags: laravel, collections

I pull in data from the database via ->get(); and want to remove a certain element based on a condition in a foreach loop so i would need something like

```
foreach($datas as $data) {
 $data->forget(this);
}
```

or i count the index or whatever, but I need to find a way to remove it because the ->forget() does only work on collection instances (not on eloquent collections as it seems) , any idea?

here is the format of my log:

```
[{"id":14,...},{"id":15,...}...]
```

so i get objects in an array.

and here is the dd();

```
    Collection {#274 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Data {#275 ▶}
    1 => Data {#276 ▶}
    2 => Data {#277 ▶}
    3 => Data {#278 ▶}
  ]
}
```

edit: i know its better to select only needed elements in the first place but thats not possible or rather not wished for because I am putting the results through a long carbon related check and wish to do something depending on different scenarios.

edit 2:
I can remove with forget(1..2 and 3) but not with 0, it tells me undefined offset?

Comment: Did you tried `unset($array[$index])`

Comment: same error, undefined offset 0

Comment: When you get the data via `get` why not remove the certain element by using a where clause before getting the elements?

Comment: did `get()->toArray()` will not work in your requierment ?

Comment: just do `get()->toArray()` and then remove by `unset()`

Comment: because i need to compare the results with each other @julian

didnt try toArray() yet, do I need to do this in order to remove elements from eloquent? cant imagine laravel making the devs to this but ill try gimme a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `map` is what your are looking for if you want to remove a specific property in the item:

```
$datas = $datas->map(function ($data) {
    // modify $data here, unset unset($data->property);
    return $data;
});
```

[See documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map)

Or `filter` to remove the whole item:

```
$datas = $datas->filter(function ($data) {
     return ($data->property == 'bar') ? true : false;
});
```

[See documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter)

Comment: filter works, also i realized in my VIEW FILE i have $data[0] in access.. really stupid sry for making this mistake and asking that question, the early morning o/